# Exibindo o total de conexões a um certo endereço de IP

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Eu tenho  um dump de rede (Arquivo PCAP) contendo ataques *slowloris*. O seguinte script mostrará o número de conexões ao IP 192.168.1.2 na porta 80:

```
/usr/sbin/tcpdump -anr myfile.pcap |
    sed 's/^.*IP \([^:]*\)192.168.1.2.80:.*/\1/p;d' |
    sort |
    uniq -c
```

que mostra:

```
  10 192.168.1.8.36684 >
   4 192.168.1.8.39619 >
   9 192.168.1.8.39856 >
   4 192.168.1.8.39896 >
   5 192.168.1.8.40195 >
  12 192.168.1.8.40196 >
   9 192.168.1.8.52288 >
   7 192.168.1.8.58529 >
   9 192.168.1.8.58639 >
   9 192.168.1.8.58730 >
   6 192.168.1.8.58835 >
  13 192.168.1.8.58851 >
  12 192.168.1.8.58852 >
  10 192.168.1.8.58882 >

myfile.PCAP é um time slice de 3 minutos!
```

A minha dúvida é: Gostaria de somar as conexões e mostrar apenas o total, ou seja, pegar a saída do script anterior e somar:

```
10 +4 + 9 +... +12+10.
```

Como fazer isso em Python? Não sei como separar o número inicial do IP:Porta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Supondo o arquivo `saida.txt`, eu faria assim:

```
with open('saida.txt') as f:
    linhas = f.readlines()

soma = 0
for linha in linhas:
    soma += int(linha.strip().split(" ")[0])

print(soma)
```

Comment: :mas eu preciso ler primeiro o arquivo. Suponha que o arquivo contendo a saída exibida seja saida.txt. Como ficaria?

Comment: Veja minha edição, se está mais claro.

Comment: poderia ajudar em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/207138/gr%c3%a1fico-do-total-de-conex%c3%b5es-por-segundo-durante-um-ataque-de-nega%c3%a7%c3%a3o-de-servi%c3%a7o

Comment: Acho que tenho tempo hoje. Já dei uma testada aqui.

Comment: agradeço muito. Estrou travado naquele problema!