# Gráfico do total de conexões por segundo durante um ataque de negação de serviço

Tags: python, shell-script, matplotlib

Eu tenho um dump de rede (Arquivo PCAP) contendo ataques slowloris:
[image: PCAP file]

O seguinte script mostrará o **número de conexões por segundo** ao IP 192.168.1.2 na porta 80:

```
tcpdump  -qns 0 -A -r 1.pcap host 192.168.91.5 and port 80 |
    sed -une '
      s/^\(.\{8\}\).* IP \(.*\)\.[0-9]\+ > 192.168.91.5.80: Flags \[S\],.*/\1 \2/p
    ' |
    uniq -c
```

cuja saída será o arquivo saida.txt:

```
 10 192.168.1.8.36684 >
   4 192.168.1.8.39619 >
   9 192.168.1.8.39856 >
   4 192.168.1.8.39896 >
   5 192.168.1.8.40195 >
  12 192.168.1.8.40196 >
   9 192.168.1.8.52288 >
   7 192.168.1.8.58529 >
   9 192.168.1.8.58639 >
   9 192.168.1.8.58730 >
   6 192.168.1.8.58835 >
  13 192.168.1.8.58851 >
  12 192.168.1.8.58852 >
  10 192.168.1.8.58882 >
```

O arquivo 1.pcap é um *timeslice* de 3 minutos de ataque. Tenho arquivos de 1.pcap a 10.pcap (cada um deles corresponde a 3 minutos de ataques)

O script Python abaixo mostrará o total de conexões por segundo:

> with open('saida.txt') as f:
>       linhas = f.readlines()
>
> soma = 0 for linha in linhas:
>       soma += int(linha.strip().split(" ")[0])
>
> print(soma)

Gostaria de gerar um gráfico do total de conexões por segundo ao longo do ataque. Alguma sugestão usando Python?

O que eu fiz:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = []
y = []

dataset = open("datasetDdos10Abril2017.csv","r") ##separacao no csv eh por virgulas
#dataset = open("dataset.csv","r")

for line in dataset:
    line = line.strip() #23,24\n -> 23,24 retira a quebra de linha
    X,Y = line.split(',') #separador eh a virgula
    x.append(X)
    y.append(Y)

dataset.close()



plt.plot(x,y)
plt.title("Gráfico do número de Conexoes por segundo")
plt.xlabel("Numero de conexões por segundo")
plt.ylabel('Tempo')


plt.show()
```

Não ficou bom:

[image: Grafico]

datasetDdos10Abril2017.csv:

```
5284,1491828000
4856,1491828180
4880,1491828360
4854,1491828540
4903,1491828720
4806,1491828900
4873,1491829080
4910,1491829260
4914,1491829440
4914,1491829620
4944,1491829800
4751,1491829980
4863,1491830160
```

COnverti as datas para Unix Time porque não funcionou no formato que eu gostaria de exibir (exemplo: 11/Abril/2017 07:50:01)

No eixo x (horizontal), gostaria que aparecessem as datas em formato "legível" de preferencia em português: 11/Abril/2017 07:50:01
E a label seria: tempo

No eixo Y (vertical):
a label seria: número de conexões/segundo

Não quero uma linha ligando os pontos no gráfico, quero apenas os pontos em preto!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fiz um teste aqui assim:

```
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> x = [1491828000,1491828180,1491828360,1491828540,1491828720,1491828900,1491829080,1491829260,1491829440,1491829620,1491829800,1491829980,1491830160]
>>> y = [5284,4856,4880,4854,4903,4806,4873,4910,4914,4914,4944,4751,4863]
>>> plt.plot(x, y, 'ro')
[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x000001CCE7C55A20>]
>>> plt.title("Gráfico do número de Conexoes por segundo")
<matplotlib.text.Text object at 0x000001CCE5FD6358>
>>> plt.ylabel("Numero de conexões por segundo")
<matplotlib.text.Text object at 0x000001CCE5FCBEB8>
>>> plt.xlabel('Tempo')
<matplotlib.text.Text object at 0x000001CCE7C21A20>
>>> plt.show()
```

O resultado foi:
[image: Um teste.]

Aí fiz um teste assim:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime, timedelta
>>> x1 = [datetime.now() + timedelta(microseconds=d/10) for d in x]
>>> plt.plot(x1, y, 'ro')
[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x000001CCE7FE4CC0>]
>>> plt.title("Gráfico do número de Conexoes por segundo")
<matplotlib.text.Text object at 0x000001CCE7FEAA58>
>>> plt.ylabel("Numero de conexões por segundo")
<matplotlib.text.Text object at 0x000001CCE7FD4438>
>>> plt.xlabel('Tempo')
<matplotlib.text.Text object at 0x000001CCE7BDE7F0>
```

Ficou assim:[image: Teste dois]

Ficou feia essa data. Então fiz o seguinte:

```
>>> import matplotlib.dates as dates
>>> plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(dates.DateFormatter('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S'))
>>> plt.plot(x1, y, 'ro')
[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x000001CCEA13D400>]
>>> plt.title("Gráfico do número de Conexoes por segundo")
<matplotlib.text.Text object at 0x000001CCEA157780>
>>> plt.ylabel("Numero de conexões por segundo")
<matplotlib.text.Text object at 0x000001CCEA142080>
>>> plt.xlabel('Tempo')
<matplotlib.text.Text object at 0x000001CCE7FD4828>
>>> plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
>>> plt.show()
```

Melhorou bastante:[image: Teste três]

Para os milissegundos, fiz o seguinte (exemplo completo):

```
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> x = [1491828000,1491828180,1491828360,1491828540,1491828720,1491828900,1491829080,1491829260,1491829440,1491829620,1491829800,1491829980,1491830160]
>>> y = [5284,4856,4880,4854,4903,4806,4873,4910,4914,4914,4944,4751,4863]
>>> import matplotlib.dates as dates
>>> from datetime import datetime, timedelta
>>> x1 = [datetime.now() + timedelta(microseconds=d/10) for d in x]
>>> plt.plot(x1, y, 'ro')
[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x0000021ECFEACC18>]
>>> plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(dates.DateFormatter('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f'))
>>> plt.title("Gráfico do número de Conexoes por segundo")
<matplotlib.text.Text object at 0x0000021ECFEAE940>
>>> plt.ylabel("Numero de conexões por segundo")
<matplotlib.text.Text object at 0x0000021ECFE973C8>
>>> plt.xlabel('Tempo')
<matplotlib.text.Text object at 0x0000021ECE543EB8>
>>> plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
>>> plt.show()
```

[image: Exemplo Final]

Aqui instancio seus exemplos:

```
x = [1491828000,1491828180,1491828360,1491828540,1491828720,1491828900,1491829080,1491829260,1491829440,1491829620,1491829800,1491829980,1491830160]
```

Converto para `datetime`:

```
x1 = [datetime.now() + timedelta(microseconds=d/10) for d in x]
```

Configuro o eixo X para formatar o `datetime`:

```
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(dates.DateFormatter('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f'))
```

Aqui faço a Matplot girar o `datetime` 45 graus:

```
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
```